# magmi data pump api from c# - Update stock and custom attributes

Tags: c#, api, magento, magmi

I am currently using the Magento API to import stock to magento, but finding it unbelieveably slow as the number of products is mounting up!

I've heard of this Magmi Datapump API, which allows me to send a list of products, and quatities to update current products stock..  is this correct?  And is there a way to call this from c# ?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 0):

The Magmi Datapump API was written with PHP scripts in mind.

You can run Magmi using other means, such as WGET or CURL as per the [Magmi Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Using_wget_or_curl)

For example, by calling:

```
http://<your magmi dir>/web/magmi_run.php?profile=<your_profile_name>&mode=update&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine
```

You can initiate an import routine.  Make sure you setup your profile first using the Magmi admin UI.  You can simply upload a CSV file to the import directory, then set your profile to use that CSV.   After calling the above URL, Magmi will open the CSV file and import the products.

Comment: Thanks! thats interesting.. I wonder is there an API similiar to the magento one for updating stock that can use Magmi's datapump.. that way you know if something has gone wrong.  By just FTPing a file over and running a wget, you dont really get any output regarding the files import?

Comment: Magmi and Magento are two separate frameworks.  Magmi was designed as a standalone importer to bypass Magento's framework, which is a major bottleneck for mass imports.  If your sole goal is to just update quantities, I would recommend building a custom Magento api extension that does more direct SQL calls to update the quantities.  That way you can customize the output returned.  You can also extend Magmi through plugins to write log files and return back results.

Comment: thanks for that! I will look into that!  You dont happen to know is there any available do you ?